# Laravel Undifined Variable in View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I cant't figure out what's going wrong with a link from my "welcome" page to a "profile" page.

It says "Undefined variable: restaurants (View: /Users/beyerdynamic/Documents/Developer/dev1/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)"

The strange thong is that I pass the Variable to my view.

My PagesController is:

```
public function welcome() {
  $restaurants = User::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(3)->get();
  return view('welcome')->withRestaurants($restaurants);
}
```

My View is:

```
@foreach($restaurants as $key => $restaurant)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="{{asset('images/frontend/profile/dummy/profilehero/hero4.png')}}" alt="..." />
                        <div class="filter filter-white">
                            <a href="{{ URL::to('profile/'.$restaurant->id)}}" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-round btn-fill">
                                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> View Restaurant
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          @endforeach
```

The Restaurants Variable is passed properly to my welcome view, but when I click the link the error occurs on /profile/{id} url.

Comment: what is `profile/{id}` you didn't shared anything about that?

Comment: Share your Controller Code for `Profile/{id}`  and `routes.php`

Comment: @Iftikharuddin uddin: If checked my Controller for Profile/¥{id}. The error was in there. Thanks

Comment: If you are satisfied please accept my answer. Glad i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
return view('welcome')->withRestaurants($restaurants);   // there is nothing like withRestaurants in laravel
```

to

```
return view('welcome', array('restaurants' => $restaurants));
```

and try again.

Comment: same thong Undefined variable: restaurants (View: /Users/beyerdynamic/Documents/Developer/dev1/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change `return view('welcome')->withRestaurants($restaurants);`

to

```
return view('welcome')->with('restaurants', $restaurants);
```

OR

```
 return view('welcome', compact('restaurants');
```

Comment: ErrorException in View.php line 182:
Illegal offset type

Comment: Did you tried the above code? Please take a look again.

Comment: You tried wrong code , try the new updated one. `return view('welcome')->with('restaurants', $restaurants);
`

Comment: Yes, I tried both! What I am confused about is. That this error "Undefined variable: restaurants (View: /Users/beyerdynamic/Documents/Developer/dev1/resources/views‌​/welcome.blade.php)" occurs NOT on the welcome view. it occurs on the PROFILE view. ( link from the welcome tp the profile )

Comment: well create a new view i.e profile and in the controller get the passed id and returned the restaurant matching your passed id.

Comment: Actually you have to pass the restaurant variable to profile view which you are not doing. There fore it is undefined in profile view. One you passed that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
return view('welcome')->with("restaurants",$restaurants);
```

OR

```
return view('welcome',["restaurants" => $restaurants]);
```

Check laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Rishi, same thing, What I am confused about is. That this error "Undefined variable: restaurants (View: /Users/beyerdynamic/Documents/Developer/dev1/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)" occurs not on the welcome view. it occurs on the profile view

Comment: If route of `welcome` page is `welcome` then try with to replace view to redirect `return redirect('welcome',["restaurants" => $restaurants]);`

Comment: no the route is: Route::get('/','PagesController@welcome');

Comment: then try this `return redirect('/',["restaurants" => $restaurants]);`